# How do you keep two branches in different repo's in sync?

Tags: git, synchronization

To keep *two (2) identical branches* in *different repo's* in sync, I'm trying to figure out how to perform the following:

Copy all commits, from a certain date, in `repo1:branchX` to `repo2:branchY`

While maintaining all comments, descriptions, meta, etc.
Not sure how the `id's` of users would work, as different users have access to the different repo's.

Comment: Have you looked into using a fork of a repository?  This might fit your need and would probably be simpler than synching two different repos.

Comment: In the fully-general case this is impossible, as merge commits require things you probably don't want to do. If all the commits you intend to copy are non-merges, you can do this with careful use of `git cherry-pick`—you can retain all the metadata except for the hashes, which *must* change. But it's probably a bad idea to do this at all.